# Unable to start application (process) using PowerShell script via Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

I have the following test.ps1 script:

```
    function startExecutable([string]$executableFullFileName) { 
        $fileName = Split-Path $executableFullFileName -Leaf
        Write-Host "Starting application $fileName" -Fore Yellow
        Start-Process -FilePath $executableFullFileName
    }

    function startMyApplication() {
        Write-Host "Starting My Application" -Fore Yellow
        $maFullFileName = "C:\Program Files\My Application\my_application.exe"
        startExecutable $maFullFileName
        Write-Host "My Application started" -Fore Green
    }
```

The pipeline script in Jenkins:

```
pipeline {
  agent {label 'agent1'}
  stages {
    stage("Run Script") {
      steps {
        pwsh "import-module ./test.ps1; startMyApplication"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the `startMyApplication` function manually in the PowerShell terminal, it starts the whatever the application I need to start. When I run this function via Jenkins pipeline, the application doesn't start. I tried other applications, it also didn't work as expected. I tried Invoke-Item, Start-Process, ampersand (&), Invoke-Expression, I tried typing “.\” followed by the full name of the file → nothing worked using Jenkins Pipeline but worked running scripts outside of Jenkins in the PowerShell terminal.

Jenkins is installed as a Windows service and logs into the agent machine as Administrator.

Kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Where does the script stop working? Is Jenkins unable to find test.ps1, or does test.ps1 run correctly but the function doesn't run? Or does the function run but the application not start? Any error logs would be helpful. If there are no error logs, you could add Write-Host statements to your function to see what point the code reached.

Comment: @MB The script continues to work throughout the execution process. When I execute the ls command, Jenkins lists two files: test.ps1 and Pipeline, so it sees the files to work with. The function seems to run but it doesn't do anything, so yes, the application doesn't start. There are no errors, the build is always successful.

Comment: So I did more research and found out that the main issue with launching my application likely requires a valid user login session.  Running a PowerShell script manually will naturally be in my current user's login session. Jenkins is running as a Service, which is not the same as a logged user session. But I don't know yet where to move on further.